# How to include template tag in django block

Tags: django, django-templates, django-tables2

I used django_tables2(http://django-tables2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) for HTML tables rendering, but my template failed to work:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block main %}
    {% render_table table %} 
{% endblock %}
```

The error message as following:

```
Invalid block tag: 'render_table', expected 'endblock'
```

And is there any alternative to the above tables2 plugin?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The docs states that You must include the following declaration before loading anything:

```
{% load render_table from django_tables2 %}
```

Comment: I have add this part in the base.html.Let me try move it out from base.html to the extended template.

Comment: I have verified that move {% load render_table from django_tables2 %} from base.html to the above template does work now.